# Search for a line in a file that matches the given condition

Tags: java, file, integer, compare

I'm writing a program for an assignment where the the user can search contents of a text file. The text file contains lines with Text and Numbers.

I want to prompt the user to enter a number, (e.g. a pin number), and a compare sign (=, <, >,)

I want to fetch and print where the number in the lines of file that matches the given number based on the given compare sign.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        System.out.print("Enter integer: ");
        String Value = input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter type (=, <, >): ");
        String Type = input.next();

        while (file.hasNextLine())
        {
            String lines = file.nextLine();
            if(lines.contains(Value))   
            {
                if (compareType.equals(">")) 
                {
                    System.out.println(lines);
                }
            }
```

I appreciate any help you can give. Thanks.

Comment: Text file contains strings and integers, the user inputs one of the integers, then he inputs an =, <, or > and if there are lines that contain, for example, integers that are less than what he entered, then it prints all of those lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not certain what you are asking, here is what I can give you from my understanding of your request.

You start off correctly getting the required values from the user.

```
System.out.print("Enter integer: ");
String val = input.next();

System.out.print("Enter type (=, <, >): ");
String operator = input.next();

while(file.hasNextLine()){
    String line = file.nextLine();
    if(operator.equals("=") && line.contains(val)){ //check if operator is equals and if line contains entered value
        System.out.println(line);//if so, write the current line to the console.
    }else if(operator.equals(">")){//check if operator is greater than
        String integersInLine = line.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");//we now set this to a new String variable. This variable does not affect the 'line' so the output will be the entire line.
        String[] strInts = integersInLine.trim().split(" "))); //get all integers in current line
        for(int i = 0; i < strInts.length; i++){//loop through all integers on the line and check if any of them fit the operator
            int compare = Integer.valueOf(strInts[i]);
            if(Integer.valueOf(val) > compare)System.out.println(line);//if the 'val' entered by the user is greater than the first integer in the line, print the line out to the console.
            break;//exit for loop to prevent the same line being written twice.
        }
    }//im sure you can use this code to implement the '<' operator also
}
```

Comment: for the if(val > compare) it says that it cant compare a string with an int, that its a bad binary operator. How do i fix that?

Comment: @Paul Oh yeah. I forgot to convert the String val into an integer. You can do this by changing the if statement to if(Integer.valueOf(val) > compare). I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Your code works for the integers the only problem is that it doesnt print the strings on the lines as well. It only prints the integers on the lines. Is that in the replaceAll method?

Comment: @Paul Yes. That method actually sets the line defined earlier. You can declare a new String and set it to line.replaceAll(...) if you would like the entire line to be printed. If this solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as an answer

Comment: Just marked yours as the answer. I'm just a little confused about this replaceAll. So would I delete the current replaceAll line? Then what would the new one have to say? Sorry for being so direct. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Paul The replaceAll method uses a regular expression to replace all non-integer values in the give string to an empty space. This string is then trimmed (all excess empty space removed) and split up by these spaces, giving an array of all the integers. As you can see, I set the 'line' variable to the string replaced so the line variable is now that list of integers with spaces between them. I hope this helped - please do ask if you still don't understand.

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm still confused. I definitely dont need to replace the non integers with spaces, because I still want to print the entire line that the integers were on.

Comment: @Paul I'll update my answer to help your understanding

Comment: what if the integers im looking for is a set of integers, like say the user inputs 12000 and >, and i wanted the results to be greater than 12000?